# iOS apps deployment shows "will install"

Tags: ios, deployment

I am trying to install iOS apps through iTunes and it syncs but shows a message of "will install" but the app is not installed. I'm not able to find what could be the mistake. Can anybody tell me by what this type of deployment issue can occur?